# iOS app not associated with Dynamic Link URL Prefix

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

I had created a Dynamic Link URL prefix in my firebase project before adding an iOS project to it.

Now I have added an iOS project to it, but /apple-app-site-association on that link is empty. However, if I create a new URL prefix, it shows the association correctly.

I am already using the previous link for production in Android and would prefer that same link can be used  as well. I could not find any way to add the association with iOS as well. If I am forced to use the new URL, I'll have to do UA sniffing and show separate URL prefix to Android and iOS users. Surely there must be a better way

Reproduction Steps:

1. Create a Firebase Project and Enable Dynamic Links
2. Add an Android Project to the Firebase Project and create a new URL Prefix (e.g test.page.link).
3. Go to test.page.link/apple-app-site-association and verify it is empty 
   `{"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[]}}`
4. Add your iOS project to the Firebase Project and revisit the previous link to verify it is still empty
5. Create a new URL Prefix(e.g. test2.page.link) and notice that the new URL has correct association test.page.link/apple-app-site-association -> `{"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[{"appID":"QWE56t.com.haha.test","paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]}]}}`

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it takes some time to propagate, it worked after a few hours. Now, the previous URL prefix has the iOS app association as well